# Android ListView inside ListView Cut the data

Tags: android, listview

In android application I use listview inside listview,
But the list view cut the data

1. the item is cut of
2. the other items I don't see at all

Here is the image shown that the single item is cut of, and the second item does not shown at all.

Any idea how can I change the height to be dynamic with the content

Thanks

**First List View Item**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:padding="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/approvedIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on" />

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/travelLocation"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="TextView" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/travelDate"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/countCompanies"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    />
                <ListView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:id="@+id/companiesListView"
                    />
        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Second list view item**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cidTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/companyName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/comapnyAddedDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="TextView" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/confirmButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
        android:text="Accept" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: If you use an item file for listing so first change in your adapter's link item file(XML) and remove fix size of layout height

Comment: There is no fix size in layout height

Comment: are you use weight for textview ?

Answer (score 0):

First use RecyclerView.
If you show the XML it will be helpful.
For the dynamic height use wrap_content for the text

Comment: Xml for what the first listviewitem? second list viewitem?

Comment: I add the xml files

Comment: I'm not sure but try android:singleLine="false"